# Is there a simulator to test out ocusdk without the hardware?

Tags: oculus, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Just downloaded the OCUSDK and have been reading thru it. I don't yet have DK2. Is it possible to run the sample code for any simulator without having the headset? I'd just like to see the images on my windows 7 PC screen.

If this is possible, please give me a hint. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Check the code in the Oculus Tiny Room sample.

If no real headset is detected, you can fall back to a debug headset. This will display a window on your screen, so you can use this to test your rendering pipeline.

You will not get any head tracking input though.